# Visual Studio confusing tooltips

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tooltip

Newbie to C #. I guess I'm dumb and just pressed something wrong.
When I installed Visual Studio, the tips worked correctly. But after rolling back the system to the restore point created *before* installing VS, half of the VS files were simply deleted.
Had to reinstall Visual Studio, and the oddities started with the hints. They do not coincide at all with what I am writing.

I tried to uninstall through the installer, plus manually deleted folders in AppData and Progra Files. All the same.
Reinstalled the system. Visual Studio seems to have pulled the settings from the Internet, because the tooltips still work strangely.
Tried Tools-> Import and Export Options-> Reset All Options. Not that.

The screenshot should show that all the text is highlighted in bold green, and although I write Float, I get abstract / class / delegate in the tooltips.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have a solution open and not just a single file? Can you open the "Solution Explorer" (no clue the Russian name, might want to try asking on [ru.so], if that is Russian :))

Comment: I think the issue might stem from the class name starting with a number.

Comment: Camilo Terevinto, It has:
Solution"Solution1" (projects: 0)

Comment: Llama, its not only class names dont hint. Even "void Update" does not prompt when type "void Upd..."

Comment: Close VS and inside your solution's folder delete the .vs folder or the .suo file(they can be hidden) and try to use Intellisense again.

Comment: shellBlazer, sadly still the same